# How to create a custom number format in Google Sheets that handles single and multiple digit numbers differently

Tags: google-sheets

How can I create a custom number format in Google Sheets that displays numbers `> -10` and `< 10` to one decimal place, but displays numbers `<= -10` or `>= 10` with no decimal places? The format should apply to both positive and negative numbers. I tried ChatGPT; it suggested `0.0;-0.0;0.0` and also `[<-10]0;[>-10]0`. but neither worked as desired.

**For column A I would like the following criteria:**

1. numbers between but not including -10 to 10 should have one digit after the decimal point (example: 3.2, -2.9, 0.6, 9.9)
2. numbers starting with 0 should also have one digit after the decimal point
3. numbers with two or more digits should have no decimal point. (example: 10, 125, -5420)

Comment: Isn't point 2 covered by point 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this custom number format:

```
 [<-9.9]0;[>9.9]0;0.0
```

note that decimal numbers greater than 10 (or less than -10) will be rounded up (or down)

[image: custom]

Comment: works perfect and I do not mind the rounding for my project thanks

Comment: See [Number format patterns](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns).